# Educational app database vs. file-based performance

Tags: database, database-design

I'm designing a database for educational app represented as a book.

Book has unites
Unit has subuntis
SubUnit has lessons 
lesson has QAlearn/vocab/grammar/exercise/tests ..

This last part is my concern in this database design.

Basic database design will have 
Table for Vocabs [word, meaning] // consider multiple translations
Table for QALearn section that has MCQ-type questions. 
Table for Grammer text with attached images
Table for each type of question
Or whatever other tables required and of course to consider some optimizations.

The case is as follow: 
If I want to load 1 lesson with its whole content it will be like that
Where id=IdOFTheLessonToLoad
Select all vocabs from vocabularies table (that may have >200k record) 
Select all QALearn questions from QALearn table (that may have >200k record) 
Select all other types of questions (that may have writing questions, true or false and others) 
Select all tests, exercises, grammar lessons

That's to load only 1 lesson from webservice to mobile app for example which will take much time. And it is required to load all lesson related information before opening any part.

My question is : Should I consider file-based storage like json files or something to save per-lesson related data ? Will that have better performance ? so in the previous case we will download the json file and locally parse and load it.

I'm aware of the redundancy issue but it will not be that problem because lessons questions, vocabs and so are not duplicated. one SubUnit can not belong to many units and one lesson can't be in two SubUnits and so on.

Answer (score 1):

1. 200K is nothing for Relational Databases
2. Store everything in relational way with foreign keys and so on.
3. Test your joins for performance issues (joining 4-5tables with less than 1M rows is not a huge problem)
4. If you think performance is issue

   4.1. Try to create index'es

   4.2. Reconsider your SQL queries
5. If above things don't help, create trigger (or application logic) which will serialize your data after each update and save it in `serialized_version_column` (Postgres has JSONB for this kind of things)

then your queries will look like

`select serialized_version_column from lessons where id = 1`